# What are the minimum packages to choose for Android SDK manager for ionic development?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools, mobile-development

When I open the Android SDK manager, there are so many checkboxes. Checking all of them will take up too much hard disk space. What are the minimum packages to choose for Android SDK manager to save disk space?

I would like to use ionic framework to develop for Android phones. My phone is based on Android 5.1

Comment: May I ask why the negative vote? May I ask what is wrong with the question so that I can improve on the quality of my future questions?

Comment: The answer will be subjective based on the needs of your project, which you haven't stated. (Minimum and target SDK version, use of Google APIs like in-app billing or maps, etc, whether you test on a physical device/use alternative emulators like Genymotion, etc)

Comment: It's up to you which `min SDK` you required to built up your app. download only that platform.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I modified the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current android minimum is 4.4 anything lower doesn't use the chrome browser unless you use crosswalk that add chromium support to early versions. I'd checkout https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/use-crosswalk-ionic-framework-android-apps/ to learn more and how to install it. Hope that helps